# Закрытое наследование в C++

Tags: наследование, c++

Здравствуйте. Я бы хотел задать вопрос по закрытому наследованию в C++

Как известно если мы пишем

```
class A {
    // ...
};

class B : private A  {
    // ...
};
```

То в В мы не сможем обращаться к членам А несмотря на то что А наследуется от В. 
Но в чем тогда смысл подобных действий если написав вот так:

```
class A {
    // ...
};

class B  {
  public :
    A a;
};
```

я смогу внутри В обращаться к членам А, а в первом случае не могу вообще ничего?

Comment: Вы к членам конкретного экземпляра же сможете обращаться...

Comment: в первом случае я не могу обращаться к членам класса B которые унаследованы от класса А так как наследование зарытое

Comment: Почему нельзя? Можно. https://ideone.com/rEOA7c

Comment: По большому счёту, закрытое наследование — то же самое, что и аггрегация. Только немного [хуже](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/priv-inherit-vs-compos.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В втором случае у вас класс B наследуется от А и содержит поле типа А. То есть, получается, что по факту в B храниться две копии А. К одной доступ есть, к другой нет.

Comment: извините я ошибкся со вторым примером. Посмотрите если не сложно

Comment: теперь у Вас первый пример в коде расходиться с описанием.

Comment: простите в чем же?

Comment: В отсутствии наследования)

Comment: сорри, туплю))

Comment: И снова Вы будете обращаться к членам поля "a", причём только публичным.

Comment: спасибо за ответы - понял свою ошибку. Почему-то думал, что при private наследовании внутри класса-наследника нельзя обращаться к членам предка на основании того, что это нельзя делать при использовании потомка вот так: instanceOfB.functionOfA()

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько сценариев, когда стоит применять закрытое наследование вместо агрегации:

- В случае закрытого наследования, возможно переопределение абстрактных и виртуальных методов.
- Закрытое наследование позволяет использовать экземпляр наследника полиморфным образом в ограниченном окружении (например, в дружественной функции). Но в общем смысле отношение ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ между наследником и базовым классом отсутствует.
- При закрытом наследовании, наследник может обращаться к защищенным членом базового класса.
- Закрытое наследование позволяет реализовать "сужающее" наследование. Когда наследник содержит лишь несколько методов базового класса (путем поднятия видимости с помощью using Base::ProtectedMethod).

Если все это нужно, то закрытое наследование будет более предпочтительным агрегации.

Вот пример кода:

```
class A
{
public:
    void PublicFoo() {}
    virtual void VirtualPublicFoo() {}
protected:
    void ProtectedFoo() {}

private:
    void PrivateFoo() {}
};

class B : private A
{
    friend void CrazyPolymorphicMethod(const A* a);
public:
    // Поднимаем видимость одного из методов базового класса
    using A::ProtectedFoo;

    void Foo()
    {
        // Вызываем закрытый метод!
        ProtectedFoo();
        // Пример ограниченного полиморфизма
        CrazyPolymorphicMethod(this);
    }
private:
    virtual void VirtualPublicFoo() override
    {
        // Переопределяем виртуальный метод!
    }
};

void CrazyPolymorphicMethod(const A* a)
{
    // 
}
```